# C++ skip multiple lines efficiently

Tags: c++, file-io, getline

I have code to read every fourth line and do something with it

```
ifstream in(inputFile, ios::in);
string zeile;
for (int z = 0; z < numberOfSequences; z++) {
    getline(in,zeile); // skip 3 lines
    getline(in,zeile); // skip 3 lines
    getline(in,zeile); // skip 3 lines
    getline(in,zeile);
    // do something with zeile
}
```

my problem is, that the ASCII file has more than 250 000 000 lines. So I am interested in the most efficient way to skip 3 lines. Does `getline` does some type of parsing `in` into a string or is this the most efficient way? I don't want to waste time for the skipping.

Comment: I think reading binary using multiply of 4096 bytes chunks and looking for new lines characters is the most efficient; not sure, need to test that.

Comment: You might find C IO functions are faster when parsing such huge amounts of data. Sad, but true.

Comment: I would expect the *most* efficient way to involve asynchronous I/O. Have a look at the [Boost.Asio library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_asio.html).

Comment: I don't see what making this asynchronous will accomplish, other than complicating your code. Async I/O is not a blunt instrument to magically make everything faster.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is *almost* the most efficient way; the only "parsing" that happens is searching for end-of-line, which you do need.

The only thing you could improve on is not needlessly storing four times more lines than you're actually going to handle. You can do that with [`std::basic_istream::ignore`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/ignore):

```
std::ifstream in(inputFile, std::ios::in);
for (int z = 0; in && z < numberOfSequences; z++) {

   // Skip three lines
   for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
      in.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');

   // Read the fourth line...
   std::string zeile;
   if (std::getline(in, zeile))
      foo(zeile);
}
```